# Comparing images for regression testing

Tags: ios, image, comparison, regression-testing

I have a drawing application that renders images (using Quartz2D). I want to be able to run regression tests to determine if a file is rendered consistently the same, so I can determine if anything broke following code changes. Are there any API's which allow me to compare screenshots (or image files), and get some similarity score.?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will suite your needs (It doesn't return a score).
But this software let you compare image and decide which parts to ignore

[Visual CI](http://visualci.com)